# 404 error on localhost using flask and html

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to create a form that takes user input, and gives its prediction. I used flask to create an API for my model, and send the user to another page displaying the prediction. I was able to get the code to work on the development server, but trying the website on localhost yielded a '404 not found` error. I've looked at similar problems, but haven't gotten the results I've wanted.

Have I setup my form correctly? Is my app.py missing information? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: app.py code]

[image: form page]
[image: project structure]

Comment: Looking at the hints given my PyCharm, I think it might be because you did not create a separate folder called `templates` for the html files

Comment: I did create a templates folder, and the html pages are in it

Comment: Can you include the full error message? Which url did you did the error?

Comment: I'm not getting an error in pycharm, but when I launch the page with the form and click submit, it redirects it to a page that says '404 not found'. This is the url that was on that page: http://localhost:63342/html5up-stellar/templates/%7B%7B%20url_for('predict')%20%7D%7D

Comment: The templates directory needs to be located in the app's root directory or search path needs to be adopted. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/ https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Comment: I may have misunderstood the structure, but I've added a picture of my directories, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template structure you’re using is correct. Looking at the error and the url, I think this error is caused by you directly opening the html file in the browser from PyCharm rather than running the app. When you directly render the file from PyCharm, the app is *not* running, so it throws a 404 error when you’re trying to link to other files.

What you need to do is in your terminal execute `flask run` and start from the url given - something similar to `127.0.0.1:5000`.